# fsharp record in discriminated union

Tags: types, f#, record

I was trying this construct:

```
type Tree<'a> =
| Leaf 
| Node of { value:'a ; left:Tree<'a> ; right:Tree<'a> }
```

But f# does not seem to support this (strange).
But then how to do this with a separate record type, one then gets
stuck in a circular dependency.

Comment: When you find yourself with a desire to say "strange", what you really mean, most of the time, is "I haven't seen this before". That's the technical definition of "strange", come to think of it, though it recently acquired more of a "wrong" connotation.

Answer (score 11):

Use the keyword `and` to deal with circular dependencies:

```
type Rec<'a> = { value:'a ; left:Tree<'a> ; right:Tree<'a> }

and Tree<'a> =
| Leaf 
| Node of Rec<'a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the "and" keyword here.

Answer (score 2):

Gustavo's answer is good.  Note that you can confine the recursion to the `Tree` type if you give the record type a second parameter:

```
type Node<'a,'t> = { value : 'a; left : 't; right : 't }
type Tree<'a> = 
| Leaf
| Node of Node<'a,Tree<'a>>

let someTree = 
    Node { value = 1; 
           left = Leaf; 
           right = Node { value = 2; 
                          left = Leaf; 
                          right = Leaf }}
```